# css loaded through linking from php but the style does not apply

Tags: php

I am just starting off with PHP, I want to separate css file nicely and link them to the page that I needed them and here is the card component and since I am just starting off, the codebase is very small and easy to debug when problem comes but I just could not figure out where went wrong.

```
// /components/item-card/item_card.php
<?php

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/variables.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/components/item-card/item_card.css" />

    <div class="item-card">

        <div></div>

        <div></div>

        <div>
           <button>ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>

    </div>

?>

// /css/variables.css

:root {

    --main-color-scheme: #182e49;

}

// /components/item-card/item_card.css

:root {

    --card-width: 300px;
    --card-height: 360px;

}

.item-card {

    display: flex;
    width: var( --card-width );
    height: var( --card-height );

}

// /index.php

<?php    

    include "components/item-card/item_card.php";

?>
```

The just above just me trying to create a item card component simply, I tried to move all the code inside item_card.css to variables.css and it works normally, but why does it not work when the code is inside item_card.css ? I also inspect the element and see the file loaded normally, I could click on it and to see the code also, but inside the resource tab, I could only see variables.css loaded.

Edit for more info: The server I am running on was the php built in server and my project was put within ~/projects/...

Edit: Somehow the php only loaded the first css and it only loaded one css only, also it only load from /css but not /components/item-card/item_card.css

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your **item_card.css** file path is correct or not.

Comment: file path is correct because I can see click on it and view the code when I inspect the element, I also tried making the path incorrect and I get a file not found error when click on it to view the code, so file path is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

CSS [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) work throughout one document. So, define the variables in `item_card.css` or [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40import) the `variables.css` at the beginning of `item_card.css` file.

Comment: For css only, the @import considered bad practice right ? I also tried copy all the code inside variables.css into item_card.css and it does not work, but opposite i copy the  code inside item_card.css into variables.css it works. I also tried moving item_card.css to /css/ folder but it still did not work.

Comment: Yes, @import should be avoided. BTW, is the PHP code part of any MVC or any library? Can you try to add echo on your code (e.g. echo '<link rel="stylesheet" ... />';) and let me know how it goes?

Comment: I temporary uses only one css and put it inside /css/item-card/item_card.css folder as workaround, then after you ask me to try echo the code, I was trying one last time by moving the code to /components/item-card/item_card.css, it works as expected and even multiple css loaded as expected also, I do not know what causes the problem. I also did the echo <link rel="stylesheet" ... />, it also works as expected but it just did not show up in the element inspect, which normally all the css linking should be seen there.